# How to focus cursor at the end of ContentEditable next to the text?

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on my code to input the html text at the end of the text in the contenteditable div. I have got a problem with insert the html at the end of the text because when I insert the html text in the contenteditable div, it will always insert the html text at the start.

Example:

```
gmail.comgoogle.com
```

It should be:

```
 google.com gmail.com
```

I have tried this:

```
var Text = $("#linkdialog-text").val();
$('#quickreply').focus().val(' ');
$('#quickreply').focus().val(Text);
```

It did not work as it will not focus the cusor to be at the end of the text as it will only display the new text at the start.

```
<div id="quickreply" class="reply-message" hidefocus="false" aria-label="Message Body" g_editable="true" role="textbox" aria-hidden="true" aria-multiline="true" contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" style="direction: ltr;min-height: 135px;width: 840px; padding-left: 25px; font-size: 13px;" itacorner="6,7:1,1,0,0"><a href="http://google.co.uk">google.co.uk</a></div>

<input id="linkdialog-onweb-tab-input" class="LW-Ke-JD-LV-J7" aria-labelledby="linkdialog-onweb" type="url" style="width: 372px;">

$(document).on('click','#ok', function(e) {

if($('#linkdialog-web-button').is(':checked')) {
    var selected_text = window.getSelection ? 
    "" + window.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange().text;
    var linkURL = $("#linkdialog-onweb-tab-input").val();
    var Text = $("#linkdialog-text").val();

    $('#editlink_background').hide();
    $('#editlink_dialog').hide();

    if ($('#linkdialog-onweb-tab-input').val().indexOf('http://') == -1) {
        alert("here 1");
        //$('#quickreply').focus();

        if(selectedNode != null && selectedNode.nodeName === 'A'){
            selectedNode.href = "http://"+linkURL;
            selectedNode.innerText = Text;
        }
        else {
            newNode = document.createElement("a");
            newNode.href = "http://"+linkURL;
            newNode.innerText = Text
            //var data = $('#quickreply').val();
            $('#quickreply').focus().val(' ');

            //selectedRange.insertNode(newNode);
            document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<a href="http://'+linkURL+'">'+Text+'</a>');
        }
    }
    else {
        $('#quickreply').focus();

        if(selectedNode != null && selectedNode.nodeName === 'A'){
            selectedNode.href = linkURL;
            selectedNode.innerText = Text;
        }else{
            newNode = document.createElement("a");
            newNode.href = "http://"+linkURL;
            newNode.innerText = Text

           //selectedRange.insertNode(newNode);
            document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<a href="'+linkURL+'">'+Text+'</a>');
        }                
    }
}
});
```

What I'm expecting to achieve is when I put the text `gmail.com` in the element `#linkdialog-onweb-tab-input` and click on a button, I want to insert the html text `<a href="http://gmail.com">gmail.com` next to `google.com` in the contenteditable div.

Can you please show me an example how I could put the html text for `gmail.com` to be display next to `google.com` in the contenteditable div??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have misunderstood the question, but it looks like a simple concatenation is all you need.

```
$('#quickreply').text(textToBeInserted + $('#quickreply').text())
```